# Add value to row of multidimensional vector c++ with push_back

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array, push-back

I want to push_back only one column in a multidimensional vector. How do I only access and push_back the vector at a specific row with an int?

```
typedef vector<int> Row;
typedef vector<Row> Matrix;
int N = 3;
Matrix restricted(N+1, Row(0));
```

And then after I run the following "working" code, the table will look like the one below.

```
restricted[2].push_back(3);
```

Resultant (array-formatted) vector: `{{}, {}, {3}, {}}`

```
restricted[2].push_back(100);
restricted[0].push_back(99);
```

Resultant (array-formatted) vector: `{{99}, {}, {3, 100}, {}}`

Resultant error when above code run: `no matching function for call to 'std::vector<int>::push_back(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'`

Comment: Can you please explain your question in detail? I mean, you want to `push_back` a `Row`, or an element in a `Row`?

Comment: I just want to know the syntax of a statement which adds an 'int' value to the end of a nested (multidimensional) vector, without needing to push_back an entire vector into the outer vector container.

Comment: I want to push back an element in a Row

Comment: You did `restricted[2].push_back(3);`, pushing back an element in a `restricted` multidimensional vector. This statement is correct.

Comment: Please see error message above.

Comment: I ran this program on http://ideone.com/KmDfQe and it compiled successfully. Please show the entire code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69107/discussion-between-shaurya-chats-and-apoorvk).